# Unexpected TabNew behavior

Tags: vimrc, netrw

I want to create a netrw sidebar whenever I open a new tab. I tried this:

```
au TabNew,VimEnter *
    \ | :Vex
    \ | :vert res 40
```

but this makes a layout like this when I `:tabe file2`:

```
tab1:          tab2:
netrw|file1    file2|file1
```

It works fine with TabEnter, but then it opens a new sidebar whenever I switch tabs. How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Obligatory: http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you're having the odd behavior with `TabNew`...

But one possible way to implement a netrw window per tab is to use a `TabEnter` event together with the [`:Lexplore`](https://vimhelp.org/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw-%3ALexplore) command, and some detection of whether `:Lex` is already opened in a window using the `t:netrw_lexbufnr` per-tab variable.

```
function! OpenLexplore()
  if bufwinid(get(t:, 'netrw_lexbufnr')) >= 0
    " If :Lexplore is already opened in a window
    " in the current tab, do nothing.
    return
  endif

  " Otherwise, open :Lexplore, resize it, and
  " switch the cursor back to the previous window.
  Lexplore
  vertical resize 40
  wincmd p
endfunction

augroup tab_lexplore
  autocmd!
  autocmd TabEnter,VimEnter * call OpenLexplore()
augroup END
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great! What's the difference between Lexplore and Vexplore?

Comment: @SamNystrom See [`:help netrw-:Lexplore`](https://vimhelp.org/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw-%3ALexplore) for all the details... In short, it *toggles* the pane on the left (multiple `:Vexplore`s will create multiple netrw panes) and it sets it up so that when you open a file from that pane, it will open in a separate existing window (preserving the netrw pane around even while you're browsing and opening files from it.)

Comment: Yeah, that seems better for what I want to use it for.